# Using static_assert() to provide better compile-time errors (than the compilers)

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, static-assert

Yesterday it took me ages to come to grips with a compile-time error caused by calling a `const` member function from a non-`const` object as in this example:

```
// my utility header
template<typename derived>
struct crtp_task : task
{
  std::list<task*> list;

  // note: cannot be const, as task::allocate_child() isn't
  template<typename... Args>      
  void add_child(Args&&... args)
  {
    list.push_back(new(task::allocate_child())
                   derived(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }
  /* ... */
};

// an application
struct my_task : crtp_task<my_task>
{
  some_data data;
  /* ... */
  my_task(some_data d) data(d) {}
  void generate_children() const    // constant member
  {
    /* ... */
    some_data child_data = /* ... */;
    this->add_child(child_data);    // error: cannot call non-const member
  }
};
```

The clang error message was several lines and too cryptic (not mentioning `const`), but gcc came up with a better error (though even more lines, but eventually complaining about me ignoring cv qualifiers).

So, to avoid this sort of thing in the future, I thought about using `static_assert()` in my utility header. My naive approach

```
// my utility header
template<typename derived>
struct crtp_task : task
{
  std::list<task*> list;

  // note: cannot be const, as task::allocate_child() isn't
  template<typename... Args>      
  void add_child(Args&&... args)
  {
    list.push_back(new(task::allocate_child())
                   derived(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }

  // note: catch call from const objects
  template<typename... Args>      
  void add_child(Args&&...) const
  {
    static_assert(false,"add_child() const called");
  }      
  /* ... */
};
```

fails, as the compiler immediately triggers an error, even if the template `void add_child() const` is never called. How else can I make this work?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want. Wouldn't `template<typename... Args> void add_child(Args&&...) const = delete;` be enough?

Comment: Sounds like a Quality Of Implementation issue TBH. The problem with the current error messages is that they fail to eliminate irrelevant details. Compiler writes: when it really doesn't matter what `Args...` is, leave it out. IDE writes: make those irrelevant lines of output hidden by default.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yes, I suppose. As you comment was before PlasmaHH's answer, I'd accept an answer by you of the same content as your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want some overload to cause a compilation error when it gets selected in overload resolution, you can use the new `= delete` feature.

```
template<typename... Args>
void add_child(Args&&...) const = delete;
```

This will generate a nice simple error along the lines of "use of deleted function `void add_child(Args&&...) const`".

Answer (score 3):

`static_assert` must depend on a template parameter to be delayed after the instantiation of the template. Otherwise they will be "called" as soon as all information is available, in your case the `false` is ready pretty early in compilation.

To solve this, I usually make it "artificially" depend on a template parameter just like in:

```
template<class FOO>
void foo( const FOO& )
{
    static_assert(sizeof(FOO)==0,"This function should never be instantiated");
}
```

Maybe in your case just deleting the function might be the better approach though.

Comment: `static_assert( sizeof...(Args) == -1, "chicken!")` technically depends on your arguments, but will always fail once instantiated. (unless you go around calling the function with at least `4,294,967,295` arguments, or are writing code on a 16 bit system where a mere `65,535` arguments.

Comment: ```sizeof(FOO) != sizeof(FOO)``` is even more foolproof.